# Install a MySQL database outside Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, containers

Can I run a docker container with mysql, and save my database (data), outside the container?

Comment: Why not run a persistent MySQL or AWS RDS server that is completely separate from your docker containers?  For most use cases with multiple simultaneous database accesses you need a single, persistent db server (or server cluster) not temporary containers with their own copy of the database files.  The performance of starting, persisting, closing MySQL over and over will also be poor with your idea.

Comment: Most of the standard Docker MySQL setups do exactly this, so that data isn’t lost when the container exits.  Is there a specific setup you’re using, and a specific problem you’re encountering?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You can use bind mounts when creating the docker container to mount a path on the host to some path inside the container:

https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

You could, for example, mount the host OS' /home//mysqldata as /var/lib/mysql inside the container. When a process inside the docker container tries to read/write files in /var/lib/mysql inside the container, that will actually be reading/writing data in the host OS' /home//mysqldata directory/folder. For example:

`docker run -it --mount type=bind,source=/home/bob/mysqldata,target=/var/lib/mysql <some_image_name>`

Do note that docker volumes can also be used for this although those work differently than bind mounts, so make sure you're using a bind mount (type=bind).

Also, I've seen at least one scenario where using a bind mount won't work for MySQL data. In my case it was using a bind mount for a docker container that was running inside a Vagrant box using a directory that was a VirtualBox shared folder. In that case I was getting some kernel/block level errors that prevented MySQL from setting certain file modes or making low-level calls to some of the files in the data dir which ultimately prevented MySQL from starting. I forget now exactly what error it was throwing (I can go back and check) but I had to switch to a volume instead of a bind mount. That was fine for my use case but just be aware if you use a bind mount and MySQL fails to start due to some lower-level disk call.

I should also add that it's not clear from your question /why/ you want to do this so I can't advocate that doing this will be good/do what you want. Only one MySQL process should be writing to the MySQL data directory at a time and the files are binary files so trying to read them with something other than MySQL seems odd. But, if you have a use case where you want something outside of Docker to read the MySQL data files, the bind mount might do what you want.